# Help with timing of spinner selection

Tags: android, spinner

In my Android app, I have a sound that I want to play when a certain selection has been made from a spinner, but I want it to play the when the user actually makes the proper selection (or just after).  My problem is that although the sound does play when they make the correct selection, as long as that selection stays chosen, it also plays every time the app starts up, when it should ONLY play at the time it's chosen.  Here is the code I have now:

```
    fitnessSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fitness_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( 
        this, R.array.fitness_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
    adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    fitnessSpinner.setAdapter(adapter4);

    fitnessSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long i) {
            Log.d("test", "p: " + position + " " + i);
            if(position == 0) {
                //First Entry
                MediaPlayer mp =  MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.bowchica);
                mp.start();
            } if(position == 4) {
                MediaPlayer mp =  MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.debbie2);
                mp.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }

    });
```

How can I make the sound stop playing whenever the app is started?  Should I wrap the whole fitnessSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener... inside of some type of on change selection, if such a thing exist?

Comment: you could add playOnce flag with onClickListener, for the way to get into the spinner, then you can set that flag to false when you play, and true when the spinner is clicked on.

Comment: I've deleted my answer - you are correct, it's not possible to use setOnItemClickListener on a Spinner even though Spinner extends AdapterView. Something I remember now though - onItemSelected is always called at the time a Spinner is first populated (even though there has been no user inter-action). I think it's a bug in the Android Spinner source. It's not always a problem but in the case of playing sounds it obviously is. Not sure how you'd work around it. If I come up with something I'll let you know. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Is there any other object that would behave like a spinner/drop down but would have an OnItemClcickListener?

Comment: What about switching to a Radio Button/Radio Group?  Would that have an event that would only fire when clciked?  Also, could a list view somehow work?

Answer (score 0):

I could think of a workaround that you could use -

You could use a dummy entry in your array. Say if you have you want to put up a array of planets into a spinner then you could have array as -

```
List of Planets
Mars
Earth
Venus
..
```

When the application launches it will show an informative message as "List of planets" and in your callback you can have code like -

```
if(0 != pos){
    //Play a sound
}
```